# Confusion regarding proving (by definition) that a group $G$ is a direct sum of $H, K$

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

For some reason, the distinction between an inner direct sum and an outer direct sum left me a bit confused regarding how one would go about proving that a group $G$ is a direct sum of two other groups, $H,K$.

Here is what I think would be required, and I would like to verify I'm not mistaken:

a. If $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$, then it suffices to prove that they are normal in $G$, that their intersection is trivial and that they span $G$.

b. If $H,K$ are NOT subgroups of $G$ (**here is where I'm not really sure...**) - I have two options when working by definition:

1. Show that $H,K$ are isomorphic to subgroups of $G$ (e.g. $G=\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}_3$, $K=\mathbb{Z}_2$ ) and then use (a) above on the isomorphic copies.
2. Show that each element of $G$ can be uniquely written as a sum of an element in $H$ and an element in $K$ (e.g. when $G=\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $H,K$ are already in the form of those isomorphic copies mentioned in (1)).

Since (a) and (b.2) seem likely to be rare scenarios (?) since they don't seem very interesting - I conclude that it will most likely be accomplished using (b.1).

Is this correct (the methods and the last observation)?

Comment: Hmm, the most direct way is to simply prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $H\oplus K$, and likely the most common one. The $H\oplus K$ is the external direct product defined over the Cartesian product $H\times K$ with pointwise group addition/multiplication. It would be weird to first prove that these have isomorphic copies in $G$ that form an internal direct product. I don't think you will such thing often.

Comment: @freakish That's if you want to show isomorphism and not equality, but what if I want equality? Also - in this case of $\mathbb{Z}_6=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3$ I suppose you're imagining using the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups or simply explicitly constructing the isomorphism?

Comment: It is not true that $\mathbb Z_6 = \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_3$. Each element of $\mathbb Z_6$ is a coset of $6\mathbb Z$. But each element of $\mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_3$ is an ordered pair whose first entry is a coset of $2\mathbb Z$ and whose second entry is a coset of $3\mathbb Z$. Two such elements are never equal.

Comment: A similar line of set theoretic logic shows that if $G$ is the internal direct sum of $H$ and $K$ then $G$ is not *equal to* the external direct sum of $H$ and $K$.

Comment: There are two useful theorems on this topic. First, if $G$ is an internal direct sum of $H$ and $K$ then $G$ is an external direct sum of $H$ and $K$. Second, if $G$ is an external direct sum of $H$ and $K$ then there exists subgroups $H',K' < G$ that are isomorphic to $H,K$ respectively such that $G$ is an internal direct sum of $H'$ and $K'$.

Comment: @Anon what do you mean by "equality"? It is rather rare for $G$ to be literally equal to the direct sum of $H$ and $K$. It can only happen when $G=H\times K$ to begin with. For example $G=\mathbb{Z}_6$ is not literally equal to the (external) direct sum of $H=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $K=\mathbb{Z}_3$. Writing "$\mathbb{Z}_6=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$" is formally wrong, even though many authors do this shortcut.

Comment: Btw, $\mathbb{Z}_6\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3$ is a special case of [the Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). Explicit isomorphism can be easily written as well. The Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups is an overkill here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusion is not correct, for the following reason: You haven't provided enough options. There are still other statements involving $G$, $H$ and $K$ which one can prove are equivalent to the statement that $G$ is an external direct sum of $H$ and $K$.

Here is one such statement that comes up fairly often:

> There exists an exact sequence of homomorphisms
> $$1 \to H \xrightarrow{i} G \xrightarrow{p} K \to 1
> $$
> and a homomorphism $j : G \to H$ such that the composition $j \circ i : H \to H$ is the identity.

In case you are unfamiliar with *exactness*, it means that $i$ is injective and $p$ is surjective and $\text{image}(i) = \text{kernel}(p)$.

Assuming the statement above is true, one directly constructs an isomorphism from $G$ to $H \oplus K$ in the following manner.

First, combine the homomorphisms $j$ and $p$ into a single homomorphism $f : G \mapsto H \oplus K$ defined by
$f(g) \mapsto (j(g),p(g))$.

Next, apply exactness to prove that $f$ is surjective. To do this, suppose you are given $(h,k) \in H \oplus K$. Use surjectivity of $p$ to choose $g' \in G$ such that $p(g')=k$. Then let $g = i\bigl(h \cdot j(g')^{-1}\bigr) \cdot g'$, and prove that $f(g)=(h,k)$.

Finally, use exactness to prove that $f$ is injective. To do this, assume $f(g)=(\text{id}_H,\text{id}_K)$, and so $j(g)=\text{id}_H$ and $p(g)=\text{id}_K$. It follows that $g \in \text{kernel}(p) = \text{image}(i)$ and so $g=i(h')$ for some $h' \in H'$. But then $\text{id}_H = j(g) = j(i(h')) = h'$. Since $i$ is injective, $g = i(h') = i(\text{id}_H) = \text{id}_G$.